# Sorting latin strings in ClojureScript

Tags: sorting, clojurescript

I did this experiment on the repl

```
(sort ["maa" "ácw" "ijl" "aez" "jkl"])
```

I got this:

```
("aez" "ijl" "jkl" "maa" "ácw")
```

The right answer is this:

```
("ácw" "aez" "ijl" "jkl" "maa")
```

Is there a way to sort latin strings in ClojureScript natively?

I asked this same question about Clojure, but I also need to know how to do it in ClojureScript.

Answer (score 2):

In [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=Intl) the answer is a [`Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) object:

```
 (let [collator (Intl/Collator. "pt-BR")]
   (sort #(.compare collator %1 %2) ["aez" "ijl" "jkl" "maa" "ácw"]))
```

Using "pt-BR" as the locale the result is:

```
("ácw" "aez" "ijl" "jkl" "maa")
```

The downside with `Intl/Collator` is that is not supported in most mobile browsers, currently only Chrome supports it.

You can also try using [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare):

```
(sort #(.localeCompare %1 %2) ["aez" "ijl" "jkl" "maa" "ácw"])
```

The [basic support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Browser_compatibility) for `localeCompare` is widespread among desktops and mobile browsers. On my machine both sorts returns the same result. But that might not be the case for every browser:

> In older implementations, which ignore the locales and options arguments, the locale and sort order used are entirely implementation dependent.

But every browser that implements the *locales* and *options* arguments also implements `Intl/Collator`.

Comment: According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization), Collator is not supported in Safari 7/8, iOS 7.1 and 8.1, IE 10 and lower, and Android 4.3 and lower. For Android 4.4, it has not been confirmed.